# How to fix no token found error while downloading hugging face?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to test the hugging face's `prithivida/parrot_paraphraser_on_T5` model but getting token not found error.

```
from parrot import Parrot
import torch
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
parrot = Parrot(model_tag="prithivida/parrot_paraphraser_on_T5", use_gpu=False)
```

The error I am getting

````
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [10], line 2
      1 #Init models (make sure you init ONLY once if you integrate this to your code)
----> 2 parrot = Parrot(model_tag="prithivida/parrot_paraphraser_on_T5", use_gpu=False)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/parrot/parrot.py:10, in Parrot.__init__(self, model_tag, use_gpu)
      8 from parrot.filters import Fluency
      9 from parrot.filters import Diversity
---> 10 self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_tag, use_auth_token=True)
     11 self.model     = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_tag, use_auth_token=True)
     12 self.adequacy_score = Adequacy()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py:560, in AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    557     return tokenizer_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    559 # Next, let's try to use the tokenizer_config file to get the tokenizer class.
--> 560 tokenizer_config = get_tokenizer_config(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    561 if "_commit_hash" in tokenizer_config:
    562     kwargs["_commit_hash"] = tokenizer_config["_commit_hash"]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py:412, in get_tokenizer_config(pretrained_model_name_or_path, cache_dir, force_download, resume_download, proxies, use_auth_token, revision, local_files_only, **kwargs)
    353 """
    354 Loads the tokenizer configuration from a pretrained model tokenizer configuration.
    355 
   (...)
    409 tokenizer_config = get_tokenizer_config("tokenizer-test")
    410 ```"""
    411 commit_hash = kwargs.get("_commit_hash", None)
--> 412 resolved_config_file = cached_file(
    413     pretrained_model_name_or_path,
    414     TOKENIZER_CONFIG_FILE,
    415     cache_dir=cache_dir,
    416     force_download=force_download,
    417     resume_download=resume_download,
    418     proxies=proxies,
    419     use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
    420     revision=revision,
    421     local_files_only=local_files_only,
    422     _raise_exceptions_for_missing_entries=False,
    423     _raise_exceptions_for_connection_errors=False,
    424     _commit_hash=commit_hash,
    425 )
    426 if resolved_config_file is None:
    427     logger.info("Could not locate the tokenizer configuration file, will try to use the model config instead.")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:409, in cached_file(path_or_repo_id, filename, cache_dir, force_download, resume_download, proxies, use_auth_token, revision, local_files_only, subfolder, user_agent, _raise_exceptions_for_missing_entries, _raise_exceptions_for_connection_errors, _commit_hash)
    406 user_agent = http_user_agent(user_agent)
    407 try:
    408     # Load from URL or cache if already cached
--> 409     resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
    410         path_or_repo_id,
    411         filename,
    412         subfolder=None if len(subfolder) == 0 else subfolder,
    413         revision=revision,
    414         cache_dir=cache_dir,
    415         user_agent=user_agent,
    416         force_download=force_download,
    417         proxies=proxies,
    418         resume_download=resume_download,
    419         use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
    420         local_files_only=local_files_only,
    421     )
    423 except RepositoryNotFoundError:
    424     raise EnvironmentError(
    425         f"{path_or_repo_id} is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier "
    426         "listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'\nIf this is a private repository, make sure to "
    427         "pass a token having permission to this repo with `use_auth_token` or log in with "
    428         "`huggingface-cli login` and pass `use_auth_token=True`."
    429     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py:124, in validate_hf_hub_args.<locals>._inner_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    119 if check_use_auth_token:
    120     kwargs = smoothly_deprecate_use_auth_token(
    121         fn_name=fn.__name__, has_token=has_token, kwargs=kwargs
    122     )
--> 124 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1052, in hf_hub_download(repo_id, filename, subfolder, repo_type, revision, library_name, library_version, cache_dir, user_agent, force_download, force_filename, proxies, etag_timeout, resume_download, token, local_files_only, legacy_cache_layout)
   1048         return pointer_path
   1050 url = hf_hub_url(repo_id, filename, repo_type=repo_type, revision=revision)
-> 1052 headers = build_hf_headers(
   1053     token=token,
   1054     library_name=library_name,
   1055     library_version=library_version,
   1056     user_agent=user_agent,
   1057 )
   1059 url_to_download = url
   1060 etag = None

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py:124, in validate_hf_hub_args.<locals>._inner_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    119 if check_use_auth_token:
    120     kwargs = smoothly_deprecate_use_auth_token(
    121         fn_name=fn.__name__, has_token=has_token, kwargs=kwargs
    122     )
--> 124 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_headers.py:117, in build_hf_headers(token, is_write_action, library_name, library_version, user_agent)
     44 """
     45 Build headers dictionary to send in a HF Hub call.
     46 
   (...)
    114         If `token=True` but token is not saved locally.
    115 """
    116 # Get auth token to send
--> 117 token_to_send = get_token_to_send(token)
    118 _validate_token_to_send(token_to_send, is_write_action=is_write_action)
    120 # Combine headers

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_headers.py:149, in get_token_to_send(token)
    147 if token is True:
    148     if cached_token is None:
--> 149         raise EnvironmentError(
    150             "Token is required (`token=True`), but no token found. You"
    151             " need to provide a token or be logged in to Hugging Face with"
    152             " `huggingface-cli login` or `huggingface_hub.login`. See"
    153             " https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens."
    154         )
    155     return cached_token
    157 # Case implicit use of the token is forbidden by env variable

OSError: Token is required (`token=True`), but no token found. You need to provide a token or be logged in to Hugging Face with `huggingface-cli login` or `huggingface_hub.login`. See https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens.
````

I have the secret token downloaded but not sure where to pass and how?

The stack trace after updating the token inside `class Parrot` in `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/parrot/parrot.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/pp.py", line 8, in <module>
    parrot = Parrot(model_tag="prithivida/parrot_paraphraser_on_T5", use_gpu=False)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/parrot/parrot.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_tag, use_auth_token=True)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 560, in from_pretrained
    tokenizer_config = get_tokenizer_config(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 412, in get_tokenizer_config
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 409, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 124, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1052, in hf_hub_download
    headers = build_hf_headers(
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 124, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_headers.py", line 117, in build_hf_headers
    token_to_send = get_token_to_send(token)
  File "/media/chinmay/New Volume/myWorks/GIT_Hub/project_parrot_nlp/vnv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_headers.py", line 149, in get_token_to_send
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Token is required (`token=True`), but no token found. You need to provide a token or be logged in to Hugging Face with `huggingface-cli login` or `huggingface_hub.login`. See https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use generate token from https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens and past it

install python lib huggingface_hub

```
pip install huggingface_hub


python -c "from huggingface_hub.hf_api import HfFolder; HfFolder.save_token('YOUR_TOKEN_HERE')"
```

if you are using notebooke

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
```

past your genrated token

Comment: Above solution worked for me.

Comment: This is a great find.  It would be useful to know what was the reference link for the info above;  I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

run the command, and act per the hint.

```
huggingface-cli login
```